# when I use sendmail in local AWS EC2, gmail regard it spam

Tags: docker, sendmail

I want send e-mail when jenkins build my project

my work process is

1. create EC2(Amazon Linux) and access ssh *(ssh ec2-user@(EC2 ip))*
2. install docker and docker jenkins > run jenkins container
3. install sendmail(i will use sendmail EC2 localhost server not smtp.gmail)
4. Jenkins Location > jenkins url : `http://13.1xx.xx.xxx:8080/` > system admin email address : `blablabal@mycompany.com`
5. jenkins > Configure System > E-mail Notification > Test configuration by sending test e-mail > insert my e-mail `myemail@gmail.com`

   ```
   Email was successfully sent
   ```

and when i check my email, but it regarded spam mail

I try `sendmail` command in EC2 instance's command line

```
# In AWS EC2 instance
$ vi test.txt ( save some text )
$ sendmail myemail@gmail.com < test.txt
```

and it regared spam

i think every email sended by sendmail, so I try sendmail in my local mac book

```
# MY LOCAL MAC BOOK
$ vi test.txt (save some text)
$ sendmail myemail@gmail.com < test.txt
```

but it regared normal e-mail, not spam

please somebody help me? thank you

Comment: Likely due to the IP address.

Comment: I found my problem,  my EC2 ip address is blocked by google, because some one create EC2 using this address before, and use this server like spam mail send machine... Unfortunatly I recived this terrible ip address

Comment: Use [Simple Email Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) and possibly setup [SPF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/spf.html) and [DKIM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/dkim.html) if you want to use your own FROM domain.

Comment: @Matt thank you but i solved my problem, instance restart and change ip address. anyways thank you i'll try SES too